# ServiceNow Compare Servers Attributes

Tags: servicenow

How can I get a diff between two servers taking all the attributes like OS Details, Patches installed, Load Balncer associated, Software installed etc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no default option to get the diff between two records in ServiceNow. Some ideas:

1. Use the list view of the table, show all the columns you want to compare and do it manually.
2. You can create a UI Page with a simple diff functionality using Jelly or Angular, etc. You would need to get the records and compare each field in the code.
3. Export the records as XML files and compare them with external tools: http://text-compare.com/, notepad++, etc.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Juarez, do you know if I can pull name of the server and associated Load Balancer Pool information in the same list ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check AvailabilityGuard. It's a ServiceNow Addon that allows Server Comparison as well as compliance standard checks and out of the box Downtime and Data-Loss risk assessment.

Another option is to check Symantec's CCS. More security oriented but potentially does something similar.

Mark.